# Add the value of two lines and create a new line

Tags: r

i'm new in R so i have some problems to modify my dataframe:

```
id <- c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
number <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,8,8,2,2)
country <- c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Belgium", "Belgium")
year <- c(2010,2010,2011,2011,2010,2010,2009,2009,1996,1996)
sex <- c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F")
disease <- c("hiv","hiv","hiv","hiv","cancer","cancer","cancer","cancer","tubercolosis","tubercolosis")
value <- c(15,1,0,2,50,120,600,47,0,0)
```

What i want is a similar dataframe but with 5 new rows that indicates the sum of the `Value` columns for `M` and `F`. Like that:

```
id <- c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
number <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,8,8,2,2,1,1,1,8,2)
country <- c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Belgium", "Belgium","France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Belgium")
year <- c(2010,2010,2011,2011,2010,2010,2009,2009,1996,1996,2010,2011,2010,2009,1996)
sex <- c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F","T","T","T","T","T")
disease <- c("hiv","hiv","hiv","hiv","cancer","cancer","cancer","cancer","tubercolosis","tubercolosis","hiv","hiv","cancer","cancer","tubercolosis")
value <- c(15,1,0,2,50,120,600,47,0,0,16,2,170,647,0)
```

Much clear:

```
> whatIhave
   id number country year sex      disease value
1   1      1  France 2010   M          hiv    15
2   2      1  France 2010   F          hiv     1
3   3      1  France 2011   M          hiv     0
4   4      1  France 2011   F          hiv     2
5   5      1  France 2010   M       cancer    50
6   6      1  France 2010   F       cancer   120
7   7      8   Spain 2009   M       cancer   600
8   8      8   Spain 2009   F       cancer    47
9   9      2 Belgium 1996   M tubercolosis     0
10 10      2 Belgium 1996   F tubercolosis     0

> whatIwant
   id number country year sex      disease value
1   1      1  France 2010   M          hiv    15
2   2      1  France 2010   F          hiv     1
3   3      1  France 2011   M          hiv     0
4   4      1  France 2011   F          hiv     2
5   5      1  France 2010   M       cancer    50
6   6      1  France 2010   F       cancer   120
7   7      8   Spain 2009   M       cancer   600
8   8      8   Spain 2009   F       cancer    47
9   9      2 Belgium 1996   M tubercolosis     0
10 10      2 Belgium 1996   F tubercolosis     0
11 11      1  France 2010   T          hiv    16
12 12      1  France 2011   T          hiv     2
13 13      1  France 2010   T       cancer   170
14 14      8   Spain 2009   T       cancer   647
15 15      2 Belgium 1996   T tubercolosis     0
```

It has created a new `T` value for the column `sex` indicating the sum `F + M`.
The new 5 lines are the latest 5.
There are 5 lines because I have to add the `F` and `M` value for each `country`, by `year`, by `disease`. `Number` is related to the country. `Id` simply indicates the id of each line.
My data frame is obviously much bigger than this.

How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't row 13 column 6 be `cancer`?

Comment: `aggregate(df$value, list(number=number,country=country,year=year,disease=disease), sum)` gives you your additional rows, I don't think adding them to data is good idea though

Comment: @Buster Don't do that. If you have a new question, post it as a new question. Changing your question after you've received answers to it is not how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quite fast solution using the `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

# calculate the sums and store it in a separate data table dtpart2 
dtpart2 <- setDT(df)[ , .(value= sum(value)), by = .(number, country, year, disease)]

# create columns of sex and id
dtpart2[, id := max(df$id)+1: nrow(dtpart2) ][, sex := "T"]

# set the same column order as in the original data frame 
setcolorder(dtpart2, names(df))

# Append the two data sets
newdata <- rbind(df,dtpart2)

#>     id number country year  sex      disease value
#>  1:  1      1  France 2010    M          hiv    15
#>  2:  2      1  France 2010    F          hiv     1
#>  3:  3      1  France 2011    M          hiv     0
#>  4:  4      1  France 2011    F          hiv     2
#>  5:  5      1  France 2010    M       cancer    50
#>  6:  6      1  France 2010    F       cancer   120
#>  7:  7      8   Spain 2009    M       cancer   600
#>  8:  8      8   Spain 2009    F       cancer    47
#>  9:  9      2 Belgium 1996    M tubercolosis     0
#> 10: 10      2 Belgium 1996    F tubercolosis     0
#> 11: 11      1  France 2010    T          hiv    16
#> 12: 12      1  France 2011    T          hiv     2
#> 13: 13      1  France 2010    T       cancer   170
#> 14: 14      8   Spain 2009    T       cancer   647
#> 15: 15      2 Belgium 1996    T tubercolosis     0
```

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(id, number, country, year, sex, disease, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- 
data.frame(
                number <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,8,8,2,2),
                country <- c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Belgium", "Belgium"),
                year <- c(2010,2010,2011,2011,2010,2010,2009,2009,1996,1996),
                sex <- c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F"),
                disease <- c("hiv","hiv","hiv","hiv","cancer","cancer","cancer","cancer","tubercolosis","tubercolosis"),
                value <- c(15,1,0,2,50,120,600,47,0,0))

colnames(df) <- c("number","country", "year", "sex",
                  "disease", "value")

df2 <- aggregate(df[,colnames(df) %in% c("number", "value")], by = list(df$country, df$disease, df$year), FUN = sum)
df2$sex <- "T"

colnames(df2) <- c("country", "disease", "year", "number", "value", "sex")
df2 <- df2[,colnames(df2) %in% c(   "number", "country", "year", "sex",      "disease", "value")]

newdf <- rbind(df,df2)

newdf

   number country year sex      disease value
1       1  France 2010   M          hiv    15
2       1  France 2010   F          hiv     1
3       1  France 2011   M          hiv     0
4       1  France 2011   F          hiv     2
5       1  France 2010   M       cancer    50
6       1  France 2010   F       cancer   120
7       8   Spain 2009   M       cancer   600
8       8   Spain 2009   F       cancer    47
9       2 Belgium 1996   M tubercolosis     0
10      2 Belgium 1996   F tubercolosis     0
11      4 Belgium 1996   T tubercolosis     0
12     16   Spain 2009   T       cancer   647
13      2  France 2010   T       cancer   170
14      2  France 2010   T          hiv    16
15      2  France 2011   T          hiv     2
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code to merge the two data frame.

Comment: @Anata That's because his question changed. Buster - I will try, but I need to take a break right now. Check back later tonight and I will try to update it.